# Java, random number and sololearn challenges

Tags: java, random

How come? I thought that "+1" is the lowest number it can generate... This is the question:

"(int) Math.random()*(65535 + 1)  returns a random number between:
Between 0 and 65535. <- answer

This is a question from a sololearn challenge.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of method [`Math.random()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random--) says:

> Returns a double value with a positive sign, greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0.

It's obvious - mathematically expressed, the generated interval is `<0, 1)`. It means, the generated number will never reach 1.0 but maximally a number a bit below (ex. `0.99`). Since you multiply it with `65535`, it will never reach `65535`. That's why you have to add `+1`.

I recommend you to use the class [`Random`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) and it's method [`nextInt(int bound)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-) which does:

> Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive)

Therefore:

```
Random random = new Random();
int integer = random.nextInt(65536);   // 65535 + 1 because the number is exclusive
```

Answer (score 0):

> How come? I thought that "+1" is the lowest number it can generate...

That is because the `+1` was placed within the brackets. See below:

```
(int) Math.random()*(65535 + 1)        //is equivalent to

(int) Math.random()*(65536)            //which is equivalent to

(int) 0.0 to number < 1.0 *(65536)     //which gives you a range of..

(int) (0 * 65536) to (0.999.. * 65536) //which gives you..

(int) 0 to 65535.34464..               //converted to int gives you

0 to 65535
```

If you want the minimum random number to be at least 1. Add it ***after*** the random operation is done:

```
(int) (Math.random()*65535) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you have the code right now:

```
(int) Math.random()*(65535 + 1)
```

You will always get `0`.

The [`Math.random()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random--) generates a number in the range [0, 1).

> Returns a `double` value with a positive sign, greater than or equal to `0.0` and less than `1.0`.

When you multiply that number by `n`, it has a range of [0, n).  Casting it to `int` truncates any decimal portion of the number, making that number `0`, and anything multiplied with 0 is 0.  The cast occurs first because it's a [higher precedence](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/) than multiplication.

Let's add parentheses so the cast occurs after the multiplication.

```
(int) (Math.random()*(65535 + 1))
```

When you multiply the truncated number by `n`, it has a range of [0, n).  Casting it to `int` after the multiplication truncates any decimal portion of the number, making the range of integers 0 through (n - 1).

If you add `1` *after* multiplying and casting, then the lowest number it could generate would be `1`.  The range before adding would be 0 through 65534, after adding it would be 1 through 65535.

```
(int) (Math.random()*65535) + 1
```